main.py cannot read module called by inside other module
I'm trying out Google's geo APIs and to try and respect good practice I'm trying to keep my api key out of my GitHub repo by putting it in a file (api_keys.py).
coordinates_api.py calls api_keys.py with import api_keys to retrieve the key and call the APIs, and when testing coordinates_api.py everything works fine and I get my coordinates printed as I expect.
When I test main.py though, which calls coordinates_api.py, I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\Git\ProjectName\src\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apis import *
  File "c:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\Git\ProjectName\src\apis\coordinates_api.py", line 2, in <module>
    import api_keys
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api_keys'

I don't understand why my api_keys module is not recognized by main.py
Here's the code for coordinates_api.py:
import requests
import api_keys

class CoordinatesAPI:
    def __init__(self, api_key=None):
        self.api_key = api_keys.geo

    def get_coordinates(self, address):
        base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"
        params = {
            "address": address,
            "key": self.api_key
        }
        response = requests.get(base_url, params=params)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            if data['status'] == 'OK':
                location = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
                return location['lat'], location['lng']
            else:
                raise Exception(f"Error from API: {data['status']}")
        else:
            raise Exception(f"HTTP error: {response.status_code}")

And for main.py:
from apis import coordinates_api

if __name__ == "__main__":
    address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA"
    CA1 = coordinates_api.CoordinatesAPI()
    lat, lng = CA1.get_coordinates(address)
    print(f"Latitude: {lat}, Longitude: {lng}")

(Here I also tried playing a bit with the import but also e.g. from apis import * gives the same error. Rather than doing trial and error I would like to properly understand what I'm missing here)
This is what my tree looks like:
│   main.py
│
├───apis
│   │   api_keys.py
│   │   coordinates_api.py
│   │   __init__.py


This happens because your program is running outside the apis folder, and every import will be looking for modules at the same level your program is running. So, in the same way you added from apis import coordinates_api in your main.py file, you would need to do from apis import api_keys in your coordinates_api.py file. A different option would be to use a relative import inside this last file, by doing import .api_keys.

If you always mean to use your package from outside of its folder, you can simply substitute import api_keys with from apis import api_keys or from . import api_keys.
Otherwise you can can add apis to PYTHONPATH environment variable, so that modules can be searched inside this folder, without having to know from where the script is run.
